# How can I give the notification to another thread while both are in infinite loop

Tags: java, multithreading

My cyclic thread is updating the data in arraylist. After completion of arraylist I need to send notification to other thread so that other thread can insert it into dbtables. But during logging to dbtables my other thread should wait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few ways to do it. Semaphore would be a good starting point. You can use this link as reference: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/semaphores.html#as-signal.

Comment: create other thread just after the list is completed.